# javascript tabs without passing any parameters to function

Tags: javascript

Hello so I have tabs using javascript:

```js
function openScreen(screen, button) {
  let i;
  const tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");
  const tabButton = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-button");
  for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
    tabContent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(screen).style.display = "block";

  for (i = 0; i < tabButton.length; i++) {
    tabButton[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(button).classList.add('active');
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-links">
  <button id="login-button" class="active tab-button" onclick="openScreen('Login', 'login-button')">Login</button>
  <button id="register-button" class="tab-button" onclick="openScreen('Register', 'register-button')">Register</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="Login" class="tab-content">
    <p>Login</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Register" class="tab-content" style="display:none">
    <p>Register</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is working, but I want to do this without passing any parameters to function and do it without using `onclick` function. But I dont image how I should achieve this.

Comment: You can try adding a `data-attr` instead of the `screen` parameter. As for the `button`, you can get that from the `EventObject` when you add an event listener to the buttons.

Comment: @Spagheeti OK we can do that without passing parameter but what do you mean without onclick  function? you need click event and call function to do that

Comment: I mean remove this part form button `onclick="openScreen('Register', 'register-button')`

Comment: @Spagheeti I updated the code in my answer a bit to reduce the clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect task for event delegation. You register one even listener for the click event on the element that wraps the buttons and the content. In that event listener, you can use `e.target` is the element from which the event originated. `e.currentTarget` is the one on which the listener was attached.

In the listener, you need to figure out if it was really the button. Which could be done by checking for a certain property (in this case for the `data-target` attribute)

```js
function openScreen(tabContainer, button) {

  // remove active class from tab-content and tab-button in the current tab container
  tabContainer.querySelectorAll(".tab-content.active, .tab-button.active").forEach(elm => {
    elm.classList.remove('active');
  })

  // add the active class to the button and the container set by the target
  let screen = button.dataset.target;
  document.getElementById(screen).classList.add('active');
  button.classList.add('active');
}

// Add the delegate event listener to all tab-conainers
document.querySelectorAll(".tab-container").forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // check if the event happened on an element with the `data-target` attribute
    if (e.target.dataset.target) {
      const tabContainer = e.currentTarget
      const button = e.target

      openScreen(tabContainer, button)
    }

  })
})
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab-links">
    <button id="login-button" data-target="Login" class="tab-button active">Login</button>
    <button id="register-button" data-target="Register" class="tab-button">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="Login" class="tab-content active">
      <p>Login</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Register" class="tab-content">
      <p>Register</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab-links">
    <button id="login-button2" data-target="Login2" class="tab-button active">Login2</button>
    <button id="register-button2" data-target="Register2" class="tab-button">Register2</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="Login2" class="tab-content active">
      <p>Login2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Register2" class="tab-content">
      <p>Register2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with data attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

short example

```
<div class="tab" data-type="login"></div>
<div class="tab" data-type="register"></div>

Then

const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

for (let tab of tabs) {
    tab.onclick = function () {
        const type = this.dataset.type;

        /*now you can do all needed actions*/
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using `onclick` properties. There are only rare cases where you want to use the event properties of an object.

Comment: @t.niese why should i avoid them?

Comment: In a larger code base, you might risk accidentally overwritinging an event property of an element at a different part of the code. And this can be hard to debug.

Comment: Ah, you mean this. I thought there was smth more interesting :) Sure, onlick should not be used in a big codebase. It's just an example, it can be rewritten with addEventListener()

Comment: Yes but if someone reading your answer is not aware of this, then this person might think that this way of adding an event listener is a neat thing. So you should avoid using these in an answer form which others should learn. And instead, use `addEventListner` in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
function openScreen(e) {
  const button = e.target;
  const { screen } = button.dataset;
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
  
  tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.toggle('active', screen === tab.id));
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', openScreen));
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-links">
  <button
    id="login-button"
    class="active tab-button"
    data-screen="Login"
   >Login</button>
  <button
    id="register-button"
    class="tab-button"
    data-screen="Register"
   >Register</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="Login" class="tab-content active">
    <p>Login</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Register" class="tab-content">
    <p>Register</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as your request. not passing any parameter. let me know at comment section if something doesn't work correctly.

```js
$('#login-button').click(function(){
  switchTab( $(this), $('#Login') );
});
$('#register-button').click(function(){
  switchTab( $(this), $('#Register') );
});
function switchTab(this_, target_){
  $('.tab-content').hide();
  target_.show();
  $('.tab-button').removeClass('active');
  this_.addClass('active');
}
```

```css
button.active{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-links">
  <button id="login-button" class="active tab-button">Login</button>
  <button id="register-button" class="tab-button">Register</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="Login" class="tab-content">
    <p>Login</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Register" class="tab-content" style="display:none">
    <p>Register</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thinking of more dynamic, reusable way to achieve this. Because if you add new tab you will need to rewrite again all this code for one tab.

Comment: This introduces a (slightly outdated) dependency to jquery and more importantly to cloudflare. When cloudflare is down the code stops working. Every visitor of this will send a request to cloudflare which may be a privacy concern. Please add a respective disclaimer to your code, when using CDNs. Doing this without a notice in the privacy statement is illegal in the EU. Moreover, nobody needs jquery anyway nowadays.

Comment: Such thinking is a little naive. I just gave a solution to this man problem. there's nothing wrong with using an external library. Your response is a little too much. if you have another solution please include it in the answer to this problem, no need to interfere too much in other's answer.